# Problem accessing ASMedia USB 3.0 to SATA external drive adapter

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive, cloning

I have a problem accessing a drive connected with ASMedia USB 3.0 to SATA external drive adapter on Ubuntu 18.04. I've seen similar questions, but in my case there are no errors reported. Here are the screen captures:

```
paul@paul-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c216 Logitech, Inc. Dual Action Gamepad
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046e:6000 Behavior Tech. Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and

```
paul@paul-desktop:~$ dmesg | tail -n 35
...........
[   13.847689] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  242.027919] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  242.048702] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  242.048707] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  242.048711] usb 2-2: Product: ASMT1051
[  242.048713] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: asmedia
[  242.048716] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 12345679B9D8
[  527.814703] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

This adapter works just fine with Windows. Surprisingly, it also works fine on another Ubuntu 18.04 PC:

```
paul@extra:~$ dmesg | tail -n 35
.............
[   13.172988] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[  292.110129] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  292.131033] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  292.131039] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  292.131043] usb 4-2: Product: ASMT1051
[  292.131045] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: asmedia
[  292.131048] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 12345679B9D8
[  292.149301] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  292.152793] scsi host6: uas
[  292.153098] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  292.153239] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     asmedia  ASMT1051         0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  292.153656] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  292.153848] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  293.182073] ...ready
[  295.232114] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  295.232116] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  295.232204] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  295.232207] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  295.232395] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  295.232614] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[  295.292610]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4
[  295.294368] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Any clues what can be wrong with the first system? The only unusual thing about it is that it was cloned from a smaller SSD using Clonezilla and some other drivers (e.g. Nvidia) are also misbehaving.

Comment: Let me guess on an usb2 port it works?

Comment: Nope. The same `dmesg` output.

Comment: create file ´/etc/modprobe.d/uas.conf`  with content `options usb-storage quirks=174c:55aa:u` for test. reboot. My ASmedia is another one

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.4 and it works fine now.