# failing ASMedia ASM1153 on USB 3.0

Tags: drivers, usb, external-hdd, sata

I have a problem accessing an external drive connected with ASMedia ASM1153 USB 3.0 3 Gb/s to SATA adapter (bridge) on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The external drive is not stable when connected to an USB3 port. I have two cables (i.e. USB-SATA bridges), one of which works perfectly on both USB3 and USB2, and another that works perfectly on USB2 **but** fails on USB3. In particular, an external drive connected to USB3 is at first read, but after 30 s to 1 min it is disconnected and reloaded in a loop. The list of devices on USB issued with `lsusb` returns

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 17ef:1012 Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
**Bus 004 Device 010: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge**
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 17ef:1011 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 17ef:1012 Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp. Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
**Bus 003 Device 009: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge**
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 04f2:b39a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bdb:193e Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV N5321 gw
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

where the ID **174c:1153** is the faulty bridge cable. I am wondering why it is described differently compared to the same one with ID ** 174c:55aa** although the name is actually inside the list of devices in the description of the latter one.

I've seen similar questions, in particular [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245994/problem-accessing-asmedia-usb-3-0-to-sata-external-drive-adapter), where @nobody correctly guessed that the drive should work properly on USB2, letting me thinking it is a known issue.
As suggested, I tried to blacklist the device, i.e.

```
$ echo options usb-storage quirks=174c:5136:u | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-uas.conf
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$ sudo reboot
```

but it had no effect. In particular, the command `dmesg | tail -n 55` shows a series of I/O errors that are not present when the same cable with the same external drive is connected to the USB2.

```
[ 2835.992349] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 2836.013332] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 2836.013341] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2836.013345] usb 4-2: Product: AS2115
[ 2836.013348] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[ 2836.013350] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[ 2836.015543] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2836.015825] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
[ 2836.015943] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[ 2836.260267] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 2836.552774] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2836.577512] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 2836.577540] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2836.577547] usb 4-2: Product: AS2115
[ 2836.577551] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[ 2836.577555] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[ 2836.580608] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2836.581063] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 1153: 800000
[ 2836.581283] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[ 2837.608560] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2837.608751] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2837.609570] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[ 2837.609812] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 2837.609814] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 2837.610050] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 2837.755088]  sdd: sdd1 < sdd5 >
[ 2837.777009] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2838.920504] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2838.945816] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2838.945821] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 72 5a c8 00 01 00 00
[ 2838.945823] print_req_error: 22 callbacks suppressed
[ 2838.945824] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 1953651400 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 14 prio class 0
[ 2839.724500] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2839.745673] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2839.745680] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 72 7b c8 00 01 00 00
[ 2839.745681] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 1953659848 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 17 prio class 0
[ 2841.200511] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2841.221665] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2841.221669] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 73 0b c8 00 01 00 00
[ 2841.221670] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 1953696712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 22 prio class
```

EDIT:
With an external drive connected via the faulty bridge to an USB3 port, the output of `smartctl --all /dev/sdg5` is the following

```
Smartctl open device: /dev/sdg5 failed: INQUIRY failed
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but have you tried running `smartctl` as described here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447185/how-to-fix-i-o-error-on-external-hdd